# How to return HTML and use it on the client with YUI3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, yui

I am using `ASP.NET MVC3` and `YUI3`.  I have a button on my view.  When clicked it does an AJAX call to my controller's action method.  This method returns HTML and then I need to take this HTML and set the contents of an HTML control to the returned HTML.

I have the following in jQuery which works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#VerifyButton').click(function () {
          $.ajax(
          {
               type: "POST",
               url: "/Server/GetChangeIncidentDetails",
               data: { changeIncidentNumber: $('#ChangeIncidentNumber').val() },
               dataType: "html",
               success: function (result) {
                    var domElement = $(result); // create element from html
                    $("#changeImDetails").html(domElement); // append to end of list
               }
          });
     });
});
```

How would I do the exact same with YUI3?  I have the following but I am not sure if I am on the right track?

```
YUI().use('event', 'node', 'io', function (Y) {
     Y.one('#VerifyButton').on('click', function (e) {
          alert('button clicked');
          e.preventDefault();
          alert(Y.one('#ChangeIncidentNumber').get('value'));
          var data = { changeIncidentNumber: Y.one('#ChangeIncidentNumber').get('value') };
          Y.io('/Server/GetChangeIncidentDetails', {
               method: 'POST',
               data: data,
               on: {
                    success: function (id, result) {
                         //var json = Y.JSON.parse(result.responseText);
                         //Y.one('#Title').set('value', json.Title);
                         alert(result);
                    }
               }
          });
     });
});
```

My action method just returns a partial view:

```
return PartialView("ChangeInformation", viewModel);
```

Comment: what is the problem/error you are facing

Comment: No problem, I just don't know if I am on the right path. I have resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this:

```
success: function (id, result) {
     Y.one('#changeImDetails').setHTML(result.responseText);
}
```

Comment: If you make a GET request instead of POST, you can do `Y.one(foo).load(url)` just like jQuery's.